# ROS PTAM: cannot locate rosdep definition

Tags: ros

I am trying to install the latest PTAM (Parallel Tracking and Mapping) as described on the Installation page (http://wiki.ros.org/ethzasl_ptam#Installation). However, when running "rosdep install ptam" it yields the following error:

```
    ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
    to system dependencies:
    ptam: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [ptam_com]
```

I have followed the exact same procedure on a different system one month ago (before PTAM was changed to catkin) and it worked. The reason for changing the system is that the GUI of PTAM is said to be successfully loaded but it is actually not showing. So we changed to a new system with an nvidia graphics card.
I tried to retrieve the old version from Github on the new system but it yields the same error.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`ROS` has its own very active [answer forum](http://answers.ros.org). So questions like this should better be answered there. Besides,

```
Cannot locate rosdep definition for
```

This indicates that "ptam" is not yet registered as the [`rosdep` key](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/0a3fbba6fce429023fcde950c85c349cc3f9d827/rosdep/base.yaml) (I'm looking at Ubuntu).

The process for adding new keys may not be documented, but you could refer to thread [like this](http://answers.ros.org/question/189743/what-is-the-correct-process-for-addingediting-rosdep-keys/) and see if you can pick up.